# Where are the Ubuntu and Ubuntu One servers located?

Tags: ubuntu-one, canonical, official-repositories

I would like to know where the Ubuntu Main repository and Ubuntu One servers are located.

Comment: Some of that information (eg Ubuntu One) is probably a trade secret. I know they have at least a US and UK server for Ubuntu updates, but Ubuntu One is almost certainly distributed over some cloud somewhere (I *think* Amazon has some of it, from something Canonical published). Anyway the whole point of the cloud is that you do not want/need to know where the data is :-)

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu One uses Amazon, so the data could be in any one of six locations around the world https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/TechnicalDetails

Answer (score 1):

As for the official Ubuntu one servers I have no idea. However, the repositories (what you refer to as the "Ubuntu" server) is really a system of volunteering mirrors. You can see these mirrors under "Software sources". They are scattered, but quite a few occur at sites of other business.

Comment: Just a reminder that locating machines by their IP isn't fully reliable, however, it's a good answer you've given.

Comment: just found an answer:  http://geoip.flagfox.net/

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One server seems to be located in Great Britain as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/41318/61218) suggests.

And the Ubuntu Main repository, *archive.ubuntu.com* is also located in the Great Britain. As also [this page](http://geo.flagfox.net/) returns result when input with "archive.ubuntu.com"

```
Hostname    archive.ubuntu.com      ISP     Canonical Ltd
Continent   Europe      Flag    GB
Country     United Kingdom      Country Code    GB (GBR)
Region  Unknown         Local time*     03 Jul 2012 05:14
City    Unknown         Latitude    54
IP Address  91.189.92.183       Longitude   -2
```

You can also get the result by going to [this link](http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&IpAddress=91.189.92.193)