# Ubuntu wont update

Tags: apt, updates

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

I type my password in here

```
Hit:1 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB] 
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                           
Fetched 88.7 kB in 2s (53.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/hhtp could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-hhtp installed?
E: Failed to fetch hhtp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Just some background, I am new to Linux.
What have I done wrong, and what is `hhtp`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your recommendation, it still doesn't work. Is there a way I can change the hhtp to http?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` won't work until `hhtp` isn't corrected, i'm writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` can't work at all, because it's a combination of:

   - `sudo apt-get update` (no problem here)
   - `apt-get upgrade` but this one needs sudo

   So use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` instead.
2. `hhtp` is probably a typo issue, must be `http` instead. To correct it, open the `software-property-gtk`:

   - using command line : `software-property-gtk` or
   - search it by typing *Software* (named *Software & Updates*)

   Go to *Other Software* and find the wrong PPA link → use *Modify* to correct the `hhtp` to `http`, and confirm.

[image]

Now *if there isn't any new issue*, you can execute your `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to have wroked. I will now re-attempt to install OpenFOAM and Docker.  Just one last thing, in the Software & Updates app, under the Ubuntu sotware tab, shoul I download from Main server, or the country I am based in South Africa?

Comment: it's better from South Africa, Canonical Main server are in Europe, in UK, you can see further details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/158926/829702)

Comment: I upvoted, but because I am new user it does not publicly show.